# Creation of a simple script that renames a file picking randomly from a group of files

Tags: bash, scripts

The idea is to play a "greeting" sound file during startup in KDE.

Inside a folder, there would be, for example, 10 audio files. Let's say, named `1.ogg` `2.ogg` `3.ogg` etc.

The file that actually plays is called `greetings.ogg`.

How do I randomly take one of these files and rename it as `greetings.ogg` without losing the 10 original files?

I am trying my best, but I'm failing miserably.

Comment: It sounds like you actually want to randomly *copy* (not rename) one of the files

Comment: Not an answer to this question, but for your example would it be simpler for a script to choose and play a random file using something like `file_to_play=$(ls greetings/*.ogg | shuf -n 1)` instead of renaming one at random?

Answer (score 8):

You cannot both "rename" a file and "not lose the original", you'll have to copy (`man cp`) the randomly selected original file to `greetings.ogg`, something like:

```
# select among 0.ogg .. 9.ogg
cp $(( $RANDOM % 10 )).ogg greetings.ogg
```

Read `man bash`, you might want to initialize `$RANDOM`.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me out, made it so simple!!! THANKS

Answer (score 4):

If your files are not necessarily named with a simple arithmetic scheme amenable to the use of the shell's `$RANDOM` variable, then another option is to use `shuf`:

```
shopt -s extglob

cp -- "$(printf '%s\n' !(greeting).ogg | shuf -n 1)" greeting.ogg
```

The ksh-style extended glob `!(greeting).ogg` avoids copying the existing file to itself - you could avoid that by copying the file to a different directory.

Comment: I think a simple symlink would do nicely instead of needlessly copying on every invocation. Still a nice and concise answer, +1

Answer (score 4):

A more elegant solution (as already suggested in comments by both [Ginnungagap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1358220/creation-of-a-simple-script-that-renames-a-file-picking-randomly-from-a-group-of#comment2326403_1358228) and [James S.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1358220/creation-of-a-simple-script-that-renames-a-file-picking-randomly-from-a-group-of#comment2328308_1359033)), would be to use symlinks, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Select among ten files at random and make a renamed copy inside /home/$user

ln -sf $(( $RANDOM % 10)).mp3 /home/x/greetings.mp3
```

**Note**: `ln` is *both* faster *and* more efficient, in terms of disk usage, than `cp`.

Note the use of the `-f` option to overwrite any link to a previous greeting sound - see [Create symlink - overwrite if one exists](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/207294/97255).

---

Alternatively, avoiding the use of `$RANDOM` (and `bash`) altogether, and using `shuf` instead:

```
#!/bin/sh

rand=`shuf -i 1-10 -n 1`
ln -sf ${rand}.mp3 /home/x/greetings.mp3
```

The use of `shuf` is taken from this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140751/97255) to [Generate random numbers in specific range](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/140750/97255)).

Answer (score 1):

After a long search, I figured it out.
It is so simple!!!!

I created a folder named greetingsTest inside my `/home/$user/` directory
so it obviously looks like;
`/home/$user/greetingsTest`

Inside there I have 10 `.mp3` files (maybe one day I will expand it to 20)
and I also have a file called `randomizer.sh` that looks like this;

```
#!/bin/bash

###///// select among ten files at random and make a renamed copy inside /home/$user

cp $(( $RANDOM % 10)).mp3 /home/x/greetings.mp3
```

So simple!
Thank all you for the help!!!

Comment: Instead of using `cp`, which makes an actual copy on the disk and is therefore relatively slow, why not use `ln -s` which creates a symbolic link and is *much* faster and does not use any additional disk space?

Comment: Thank you very much!!! id did a man ln and I went with ln-sf THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Awww yiss. :) linux/unix filesystems do this thing and it's really cool; when folks move over from Windows they usually don't know about it but it's a great way to do a lot of different things.